# возможно ли преобразовать Array в int[,] C#

Tags: c#, массивы, конвертация

Задача возникла следующая: создать метод, расширяющий массив произвольной размерности.

К сожалению базовые конструкторы массивов имеют синтаксис, завязанный на размерности. Однако класс **Array** имеет метод **CreateInstance(*Type, Int32[]*)**, позволяющий легко создать нужный массив... Тем не менее как преобразовать **Array** в стандартный тип, сохраняя заданную структуру, я, увы, не нашёл. Метод **Copy()** в этой ситуации работать отказывается.

Помогите, если кто в курсе, или объясните, пожалуйста, если не понимаю чего-то принципиального.

Comment: А структуру массива можно в студию? Например массив array[1,2,3,4,5] и даже теоретически не преобразую, потому что нет никакого тз,что с чем преобразовывать, какие действия выполнять?

Comment: как ты пробовал использовать метод Copy? почему ты думаешь, что он отказывается работать?

Comment: @Grundy Array.Copy считает двумерный массив очень длинным одномерным - и не сохраняет строки (наверное)

Answer (score 1):

Так все массивы в c# наследуются от Array, Вам должно помочь приведение типов

```
Array myArr = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 2, 3, 4);
int[,,] myvar = (int[,,])myArr;
```

Comment: это было первое, что я проверил. И, увы, оно так не работает. А точнее работает, но как-то совсем не так, пытаясь привести его к массиву массивов

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем за комментарии. Причина как всегда оказалась в глупости: бегая от костылей, засунул в CreateInstance GetType()... но не элемента, а массива. Мозг чуть не взорвался от непонимания, а браузер от вкладок с msdn'а, а всё оказалось куда проще (рукожопость непонимающего)